# How to merge 2 stream topics into one with some logic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to simulate a real-time data stream from static CSV files.

There are 2 CSV files.

exchange.csv: daily currency exchange rates

```
DATE        CURRENCY    RATE
2020-01-01  USD         1.1
2020-01-03  USD         1.2
```

> Rate 1.1 means: 1 EUR = 1.1 USD

balance.csv: account balance state

```
ACCOUNT     BALANCE     CURRENCY    DATETIME
A           100         USD         2020-01-02 0:00
B           200         EUR         2020-01-02 0:00
A           150         USD         2020-01-02 12:00
B           200         EUR         2020-01-02 12:00
A           150         USD         2020-01-03 0:00
B           300         EUR         2020-01-03 0:00
A           50          USD         2020-01-03 12:00
B           0           EUR         2020-01-03 12:00
```

I am using [Spool Dir](https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-connect-spooldir/) to read into 2 topics:

- balance_topic
- exchange_topic

I want to merge two stream topics into one so currency in balance data is updated according to the exchange rate:

[image]

The result topic should be something like this:

```
ACCOUNT     BALANCE     CURRENCY    DATETIME
A           100         USD         2020-01-02 0:00
B           220         USD         2020-01-02 0:00
A           150         USD         2020-01-02 12:00
B           220         USD         2020-01-02 12:00
A           150         USD         2020-01-03 0:00
B           360         USD         2020-01-03 0:00
A           50          USD         2020-01-03 12:00
B           0           USD         2020-01-03 12:00
```

How can I implement such logic?

Comment: I suggest checking  ksqlDB if you‘re using the confluent platform (example: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/tutorials/etl/)

Comment: @AydinK. thank you for your suggestion! I will take a look.